# Efficient Search for specific Terms in symbolic Expression

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement, symbolic, expression-manipulation, symbols

I have a large symbolic expression with six variables `a,b,c,d,e,f` per term, roughly like this:

```
expr=a^2 b c d^2 + 1/2 a b (b + I d) e^3 - 1/8 I a (c + 1/2 I (c + I d))^2 (I b + 1/2 (c + I d)) e f
```

I want to test whether `expr` contains terms with `c` and `d` and `e` and `f`. In the example above, there is one term that fulfills the requirement: `(-(1/8)-I/16) a b c d e f`.

I want a function `g[x]`, which returns a new expression, only containing terms with `c*d*e*f`.

I can solve it using `Expand` and symbolic replacements, but this is very slow, and I was hoping for a much faster way. Does anybody have a suggestion for a faster implementation?

Here is the example code - which first creates the expression (such that we can compare our solutions), then defines `g[x]`, runs it and prints the result and time:

```
(* Same seed for fair comparison *)
SeedRandom[1];

(* Creating one large expression that has to be analysed *)
func = 0;
For[ii = 1, ii <= 100, ii++,
  rndFull = Product[RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d, e, f}], {i, 6}];
  For[jj = 1, jj <= 60, jj++,
   rndVar0 = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d, e, f}];
   rndVar1 = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d, e, f}];
   rndVar2 = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d, e, f}];
   rndFull = rndFull /. {rndVar0 -> 1/2*(I*rndVar1 + rndVar2)};
   ];
  func += Simplify[Exp[(I*\[Pi])/2*RandomInteger[4]]]*rndFull;
  ];

(* g[x] works correctly but is very slow *)
g[expr_] := (Return[Expand[ZERO*expr] /. {ZERO*c*d*e*f -> c*d*e*f} /. {ZERO -> 0}])


CurrTime = AbsoluteTime[];
Print[g[func]]
(* (-(3066695705460323281748465708319/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)-(592396087826201433092643851215 I)/170141183460469231731687303715884105728) a^2 c d e f-(28061855884788386235225/1267650600228229401496703205376-(1188923985339435970275 I)/158456325028528675187087900672) a b c d e f-(23306256125181506635725/2535301200456458802993406410752-(47084620130455206162825 I)/5070602400912917605986812821504) b^2 c d e f *)
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - CurrTime] (* 4.5930638 sec *)
```

Does anybody have a suggestion for a faster implementation?

Comment: So in your example `expr`, `a b c d e f` counts but `a d c d e f` doesn't? This will be very dependent on how the terms in the expression are arranged. Would you want it to generalise to, for example, picking out terms involving `b d e f`?

Comment: If you're just interested in the literal occurrence of `c d e f` as a string in the expanded form of `expr`, and you're not worried about the order depending on _Mathematica_'s canonical ordering, you could use `Pick[#, StringContainsQ["c d e f"] /@ ToString /@ #] &@(List @@ Expand@expr)`.

Comment: @aardvark2012 No, the order does not matter when doing /. Mathematica will match `a b` or `b a` for the pattern `a b`. Compare `a b c/.a b->x` and `a b c/.b a->x` they give same answer which is `c x`. Your string solution will not work, since only `a b` will be matched and not `b a` as in the case of general pattern

Comment: As you note, all the time seems to be being spent on `Expand` (`Simplify` is even worse). `Coefficient[func, c d e f] c d e f` returns the same as `g` and is almost order of magnitude faster when they're both passed already `Expanded` (or `Simplify`ed) expressions (and marginally faster when the argument isn't pre-`Expanded`, but there's not a lot to choose between them).

Comment: @aardvark2012 thanks for your solution; unfortunatly it also uses `Expand`, thus its as fast/slow as my original solution. Also it gives a slightly different result, as it also returns expressions like `b c d e f^2` which I do not want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another faster solution:

```
prune[X_][expr_] := Select[expr, MemberQ[#, X, \[Infinity]] &]
h[expr_] := Plus@@Cases[Expand@prune[c]@prune[d]@prune[e]@prune[f]@expr, c d e f X_] 
r1 = g@func; //Timing
r2 = h@func; //Timing
r1 == r2
```

> {12.0938, Null}
>
> {1.39063, Null}
>
> True

We see a speed up of almost a factor 10.

Comment: An operator version of `prune` would be `prune[x_] = Select[Not@*FreeQ[x]]`.

Comment: Yes, and I'm sure the pruning could be made more efficient. However, the step after the prune is the most time consuming.

Comment: Very nice solution, and indeed in my test more than 5 times faster. Thanks +50

Answer (score 4):

The following is slightly faster:

```
r1 = With[{dd = D[func, c, d, e, f]},
    Expand[c d e f Block[{c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0}, dd]]
]; //AbsoluteTiming

r2 = g[func]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {2.8915, Null}
>
> {3.49264, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Wow that is very clever, using a derivative :-) Didn't think about that. Thanks for the solution.